# Can't find my null pointer - recursion in Java / Netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to write a screensaver type program, but I'm getting a null pointer exception that I can't trace. I'm looking through a directory and what I think is happening is that when the 'walk' reaches a folder rather than a file, it's throwing the exception. I just can't work out what do do about this! Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;


public class Recursion {

    public void walk(String path) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        String[] fileArray = new String[list.length];
        int i = 0;
        if (list == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (File f : list) {

            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                walk(f.getAbsolutePath());

            } else if (f.isFile()) {
                String outPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println("File:" + outPath);
                fileArray[i] = outPath;
                i++;

            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < fileArray.length; j++) {//WILL NEED TO CONVERT TO SOME FORM OF WHILE LOOP LATER
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();//Initiates random generator
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(fileArray.length);////Limits max random to length of folder array
            String files = fileArray[randomInt];//Chooses a filename based on random number

            Imagetime go = new Imagetime();
            go.Show(files);

        }

}
```

}

And here is the System out and error:

```
File:c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\From East (Capel Curig) 16-6-14 - No Cars.png
File:c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\From East (Capel Curig) 16-6-14.jpg
File:c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\From East (Capel Curig) 16-6-14.png
File:c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\IMG_7457.png
File:c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\test.png
Displaying image...c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\test.png
Displaying image...c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\IMG_7457.png
Displaying image...c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\IMG_7457.png
Displaying image...c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\From East (Capel Curig) 16-6-14.jpg
Displaying image...c:\Users\Guy\Pictures\Edited\Geography\Snowdon\From East (Capel Curig) 16-6-14 - No Cars.png
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at screensaver.Imagetime.Show(Imagetime.java:40)
    at screensaver.Recursion.walk(Recursion.java:49)
    at screensaver.Recursion.walk(Recursion.java:31)
    at screensaver.ScreenSaver.main(ScreenSaver.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

The "Displaying image....." comes from within the Imagetime class.

The result of this is that the few files in the initial directory are displayed, but then no more from other folders as the exception brings it all to a close.

Everything else is working precisely how I expected, but I've no idea how to remove this issue. If I remove the 'walk' for

```
if(f.isDirectory()){
     walk(f.getAbsolutePath())
}
```

and leave the if condition empty, I get no images displayed at all.

Someone please help, this has been driving me mental for too long!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Showing the code of Imagetime class will be useful.

Comment: It's OK the problem is solved now. I didn't add the code from 'Imagetime' as it's a bit long and messy at the moment - needs a lot of work before I'd dare show it on here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have any directories in your folder your array length will be longer than your number of files leaving a set of null entries at the end of your array.  When your random number hits one of these you will get this error. I suggest switching your array to a list to eliminate this.